# Why my console log is returning HTMLCollection0?

Tags: javascript

I trying to return that text inside of the list but instead Im getting htmlcollection0

my JS:

```
 Array.from(document.getElementById("main-menu").getElementsByTagName("li")).forEach(
        (x) =>
          (x.onclick = () =>
            console.log({
              event_name: "menu item clicked",
              menu_item: x.getElementsByTagName("li"),
            }))
      );
```

my html:

```
<div id="main-body">
      <ol id="main-menu">
        <li class="selected">Shop Spirits</li>
        <li>Shop Bourbon</li>
        <li>Shop Scotch</li>
        <li>Shop Rum</li>
      </ol>
```

Comment: You're setting `menu_item` to the list of all `li` elements nested inside `x`. What are you expecting it to log instead of `HTMLCollection`?

Comment: There are no nested `li` elements, so the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

`x.getElementsByTagName('li')` returns all the `li` elements nested inside `x`. There aren't any, so that returns an empty NodeList.

If you want to log the text of the clicked item, use `x.innerText`, there's no need to search for anything.

```js
Array.from(document.getElementById("main-menu").getElementsByTagName("li")).forEach(
  (x) =>
  (x.onclick = () =>
    console.log({
      event_name: "menu item clicked",
      menu_item: x.innerText
    }))
);
```

```html
<div id="main-body">
  <ol id="main-menu">
    <li class="selected">Shop Spirits</li>
    <li>Shop Bourbon</li>
    <li>Shop Scotch</li>
    <li>Shop Rum</li>
  </ol>
```